# Convert Model Relationship with HasManyDeep Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I have one model relationship using `HasManyThrough` but I cant load realtionship on product, and I found this package https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep can help to convert my model relationship with `HasManyDeep`

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(ProductVariant::class, MerchantProduct::class, 'merchant_id', 'id', 'id', 'product_variant_id')
        ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_variants.product_id')->select('products.*')->distinct();
}
```

i try to changes to this, but still wrong result....

```
 public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyDeep(
        Product::class,
        ['merchant_products', ProductVariant::class],
        ['merchant_id', 'product_id', 'id'],
        ['id', 'product_variant_id', 'id']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i found :)

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyDeep(
        Product::class,
        ['merchant_products', ProductVariant::class],
        [null, 'id', 'id'],
        [null, 'product_variant_id', 'product_id']
    )->distinct();
}
```

Comment: Might want to share a bit more than the solution, describe what you did wrong. Thanks